# Как получить fileid для скачивания историй пользователей из Telegram через tdlib?

Tags: .net, tdlib

Я могу получить активные истории и в архиве, но не могу понять как получить fileid истории и скачать ее. Если использовать метод GetStory то там возвращается информация про историю но без ссылки на нее.